# Slack oauth redirect uri "signature" param

Tags: botframework, slack-api

When a user authorizes our bot, they get redirected to our site with 2 query params, `teamid` and `signature`, what's that second param for? I haven't found any docs about it.

Is it the `signature` related to WHO installed the bot?

Comment: I'm interested in this too!

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful, we built a new Slack connector to control the whole OAuth flow (https://github.com/suttna/botbuilder-slack) that means you will get all the information from Slack, the most important thing is WHO installed your bot, something that you can't get through botframework connector.

And here a sample

```
import * as restify from 'restify'
import { UniversalBot, IEvent, IIdentity } from "botbuilder"
import { SlackConnector } from "botbuilder-slack"

type BotCache = { [key: string]: { identity: IIdentity, token: string } }

const botsCache: BotCache = {}

const connectorSettings = {
  botLookup: (teamId: string) => {
    const botEntry = botsCache[teamId]

    if (botEntry) {
      return Promise.resolve([botEntry.token, botEntry.identity.id] as [string, string])
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Bot not found'))
    }
  },
  botName: process.env.SLACK_BOT_NAME,
  verificationToken: process.env.SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN,
  clientId: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirectUrl: process.env.SLACK_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL,
  onOAuthSuccessRedirectUrl: process.env.SLACK_OAUTH_ON_SUCCESS_REDIRECT_URL,
  onOAuthErrorRedirectUrl: process.env.SLACK_OAUTH_ON_ERROR_REDIRECT_URL,
  onOAuthAccessDeniedRedirectUrl: process.env.SLACK_OAUTH_ON_ACCESS_DENIED_REDIRECT_URL
}

const connector = new SlackConnector(connectorSettings)

const bot = new UniversalBot(connector)
const app = restify.createServer()

app.use(restify.plugins.queryParser())
app.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser())

bot.on('installationUpdate', (event: IEvent) => {
  console.info(`New bot installed by ${event.sourceEvent.SlackMessage.user_id}`)

  botsCache[event.sourceEvent.SlackMessage.team_id] = {
    identity: event.address.bot,
    token: event.sourceEvent.ApiToken
  }
})

bot.dialog('/', (session) => {
  session.endDialog('pong')
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Bot is listening...")
})

app.post('/slack/events', connector.listenEvents())
app.post('/slack/interactive', connector.listenInteractiveMessages())
app.post('/slack/command', connector.listenCommands())
app.get('/slack/oauth', connector.listenOAuth())
```